# Get the View in the Controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

I want to ask how I can get the view I am showing in my controller.
The reason I want to do this is that a `DirectoryChooser` Dialog requires an `ownerWindow` in order to work correctly.

Is there any other solution?

```
    DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    File file = directoryChooser.showDialog(/*I need a javafx.stage.window here!*/);
```

Comment: Do you have any a reference to any other control or scene graph element while using the DirectoryChooser?

Comment: Yes, I press a button to open the DirectoryChooser. That's a good idea actually.

Comment: then just go with `button.getScene().getWindow()`. This will return the current window reference on which the button is placed.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha if you want you can put that as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fetch the current window's reference from any scene graph element that is currently being shown.

```
element.getScene().getWindow()
```

For example, if the dialog opens up from the action of a button, you can fetch the window from the button reference. The code would look like :

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    File file = directoryChooser.showDialog(button.getScene().getWindow());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not suggesting this is the **right** way of doing this but this is cretainly **a** way. The arguments against using `public static` should be born in mind here.

```
public class App extends Application {

  public static App mainApp;
  public static Stage mainStage;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    // Remember me.
    mainApp = this;
    mainStage = stage;
```

You can then use:

```
    File newLocation = chooser.showDialog(App.mainStage);
```

Comment: For obvous reasons this is not a good approach. But it also restricts the to a single stage that can be the owner of the dialog. If the program opens more than 1 stage that use the same controller class and allows to open the dialog, this approach doesn't work anymore (at least not without some really ugly workarounds).

Comment: @fabian - I totally agree - and would not recommend this route at all. However, in the context of `protected void handleFileOpenAction(ActionEvent event)` it is difficult to gather a `Scene` from the `ActionEvent` - or is it?

Comment: If it's activated by a UI interaction of the user `event.getSource()` should yield a `Node` (and ItachiUchia's approach can be used).